# kafka + too many open files between Kafka brokers or may between broker and clients

Tags: linux, apache-kafka

we are facing very major problem with our Apache Kafka servers
our Kafka servers are creased because "*Too many open files*"

we have production Kafka cluster with *7 machines* , while Kafka version is *0.1*

we already increases twice the "*kafka_user_nofile_limit*" to *500000* , while the original value is *128000*

but again we are hit the high value and brokers are crashed

*additional we can see clearly that many lines as "Too many open files" are in Kafka logs*

we saw the following *Jira* case

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3317

but we not see what is the solution for this jira or what is the workaround for this major problem ?

**from jira**

```
 Bug
Status:OPEN
Priority: Major
Resolution:Unresolved
Affects Version/s:
0.9.0.0, 0.9.0.1
Fix Version/s:None
Component/s:None
Labels:None
Environment:CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1
Flags:
Important
Description
there is much open files in my java app client which write msg to kafka broker, i used

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
<artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
<version>0.9.0.1</version>
</dependency>
new api to write msg. when i use

lsof -p 8780 | wc -l
19184
lsof -p 8780 | grep XmlIpcRegSvc | wc -l
4920
lsof -p 8780 | grep pipe | wc -l
9576
lsof -p 8780 | grep eventpoll | wc -l
4792
where 8780 is my java app pid.

java 37121 app *796u IPv6 960673997 0t0 TCP mad183:50213->mad180:XmlIpcRegSvc (ESTABLISHED)
there are many ESTABLISHED XmlIpcRegSvc , and seems not closed.
and It likes use ipv6 .
```

example from my kafka machines

```
 more /etc/security/limits.d/kafka.conf

# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

kafka   - nofile   500000
kafka   - nproc    65536
```

Comment: not sure what platform you are running on, but you might want to check the file descriptor limit on OS level.
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/

Comment: no this isn't the case , I can set higher value of file descriptor , but the number of files is growing without limit , so this is the problem , I know well how to set the limit , but number of files is growing , and this is not make sense  ( other kafka have 20% from the limit of file descriptor

Comment: please take a look on the jira bug

Comment: Seems no updates on this KAFKA-3317 bug at all and can't seem to find anything related in the code repo either...  How do you start the kafka process? just wanted to share that years ago I ran into similar issue max out file descriptors in cassandra although I have increased nofile system wide, turns out it was because I was using supservisord to start cassandra and file limits was being override by supervisord with 1024!